# button link with font awesome not working

Tags: html, css, button

I've tried re-coding it different ways and I'm not sure why it's not working. I'm trying to make a button that when pressed will send the user to Github all while having a font awesome icon.

```
 <a href="https://github.com/"> <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-github" 
    aria-hidden="true">GitHub</i></a>
```

Comment: `I've tried re-coding it different ways` Show us that. Also check your console if there are no 404 errors for font-awesome css.

Comment: this has nothing to do with java.

Comment: make sure you are using the latest CDN version of FontAwesome. If you are hosting FontAwesome on your own server, make sure you have downloaded the latest version.

Comment: Why it cannot be used a single url? Just add an extra-class to emulate button-representation `<a class="button fa fa-github"  href="https://github.com/">GitHub</a>`

Comment: @C0dekid, URL will be opened earlier than the form submitted

Comment: @FieryCat Oeps I see! Sorry :p

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You should have the font awesome installed locally or by CDN

**By CDN**
You should put this code on the `<header>`

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://github.com/'"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>GitHub</button>
```

**OR**

```
<a href="https://github.com/"><i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>GitHub</a>
```

Comment: @fieryCat If you see there is a wrong html, and there is a note about the icon

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' />
  
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://github.com/"> <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-github" 
    aria-hidden="true">GitHub</i></button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

So because I was writing this in codepen I had to add a target="_blank" to open the page in a new tab and that fixed the issue.

Thank you for the help